# Modelica - Is it possible to set name of a variable as the value of another variable?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I’m quite noob in Modelica language and I’d appreciate any help about this simple issue.
I’d like to know if it’s possible to write a variable name as a function of other variable in order to shorten the general code.
Here there is an example about what I’d like to do.

Thanks in advance!

```
model example

  Real variable1;
  Real variable2;
  Real variable3;

equation

  for i in 1:3 loop

    variable(i)= […]
    
  end for;

end example;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use arrays in some way. This is similar to the code above, but perhaps you only need the array and not variable1 … variable3.

```
Real variable1;
Real variable2;
Real variable3;
Real variables[3] = {variable1,variable2,variable3};
equation
  for i in 1:3 loop
    variables[i] = /* … */;
  end for;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I really appreciate it. I thought about that, but in my case I'm (probably) not able to use arrays. I have the same submodel repeated three time in my top-level model (model1, model2 and model3), so I'd like to use this strategy for calling the variables that rely on this models from my top-level model. Example (model(i).temperature). I know that I can fix this inside each submodel, but I just wanted to know if it'd be possible at the top level as well.

Comment: @Javier1124: I suggest asking a new question with this additional information. From your short description, I would say vectorized components, inner/outer or a bus could be a solution. It depends on what you want to do with the temperatures.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've already posted it, let's see if it clearer.